# How do I create a hotkey to change default sound device with Logitech keyboard?

Tags: audio, keyboard, default, device, logitech

It's really annoying to have to manually change default sound device, especially when I'm playing a game.

How can I program a hotkey to do this?

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1: Download nircmd**

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html

The download link is at the bottom of this page. This will enable you to manipulate your default sound device via command line

**Step 2: Unzip and move executables to your system directory**

This will ensure you can just use "nircmd" in future steps instead of worrying about directory context. You can skip moving the directory if you'd like, you'll just need specify an absolute path for your shortcut in step 4

**Step 3: Give your sound devices meaningful names**

1. Right click the sound devices icon in your system tray, select playback devices
2. Right click sound device, select Properties
3. Change name to something unique (Speakers/Headphones is fine as long as nothing else is named that!)
4. Do this for each device you need to toggle between

**Step 4: Bind your G Keys**

1. Open the Logitech app and select the tab at the bottom that looks
   like a G key
2. Select the GKey you want to create a binding for (there should be a down carrot when you hover over it)
3. Select Assign New Command
4. Select Shortcut
5. Name it something you will recognize, like "Use Speakers"
6. Enter the following for the command (secondtextbox), changing DeviceName to the name of the device from step 3:
   *nircmd setdefaultsounddevice "DeviceName" 1*
7. Repeat these steps for each device you want to toggle between

That's it! Your keys are ready to use!